# Running Parellel selenium Test Cases Without TestNG or Junit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

How to run  Selenium Test Cases parallely without using TestNG or JUnit.

Currently i am using the command

Client(Node) command :

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node -hub 
    Protocol://host:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS maxInstances=3.

But its not working.

**I Need to execute one/many test cases parelley(at a time 5) in Firefox**

Comment: When I worked with Selenium, you could only run one instance of Firefox on a machine. You would need to set up a group of 5 machines to run Firefox 5 times. You haven't told us if you have 5 machines set up in your grid.

Answer (score 1):

*Java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node -hub Protocol://host:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS maxInstances=3.
But its not working.*

It won't work. By running the above command you are setting up selenium grid to run 3 instances of test **IF and When it gets** 3 requests. You need to write the logic to pass three instances of tests pointing to the hub in parallel for the node to work its magic.

To run tests in parallel using java, you need to create logic using multithreading. You should take care to

- make your classes thread safe
- Specify which tests to run
- Create a report of testing so that others can know what your test is doing

Or you can use JUnit or testNG which will do most of these for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i will try testNG framework

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using Maven Surefire, which has parallel running capability.  You would only want to use TestNG if you need to parameterize.  Surefire creates a pretty ok test report also.