# How to run only selected selenium test scripts without TestNG?

Tags: selenium

I have few selenium test scripts as a separate class files in Eclipse. If I wants to execute only the selected scripts (eg: 4 out of 10 scripts) without TestNG how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Parellel selenium Test Cases Without TestNG or Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564694/running-parellel-selenium-test-cases-without-testng-or-junit)

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya i don't wants to run scripts in parallel. I just wanted to run the selected scripts like how we configure in testng.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can create objects form each class you want to execute in the class you intend to have the java main function. Then simply call the test cases within the main function an run. Ex:

```
import com.Testcase9;

Testcase9 tc9 = new Testcase9();

public static void main(String[] args){
 tc9.verifyText();
}
```